# Blinding flash. Set background color when creating new window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Using GLFW to create the main window

Example c++

```
wS->win->hdl = glfwCreateWindow(wS->win->width, wS->win->height, wS->win->appName, NULL, NULL);
```

The created window for a moment has a white background, until openGL is setup and rendering the correct color (between `glfwCreateWindow` and first call to `glClear`).

In dark mode on a large monitor it is almost painful having a sudden flash of full white.

My current solution is to open the window as small as possible, resizing it when openGL is ready. This is a hack and it would be nice to be able to set the default window background color to match the current display mode of the OS (dark / light modes)

Answer (score 0):

### A better hack?

After some trial and error I found a solution that is still a hack but much better than resizing.

Immediately after creating the window with `wS->win->hdl = glfwCreateWindow((wS->win->width, wS->win->height, wS->win->appName, NULL, NULL);` call `glfwSwapBuffers(wS->win->hdl);`

The default state of the back buffer seams to be black and overwrites the white window content.